# Including a package in android source code

Tags: android, android-source

I am modifying [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/) (CM 7) Source code,

i want to include "Cyanogen/packages/apps/phone/src/com/android/phone/CallNotifier.java" in the "Cyanogen/frameworks/base/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/LockPatternGuardview.java" file. I added "import com.android.phone.CallNotifier;" in the LockPatternGuardview.java file and upon compiling i get this error.

LockPatternKeyguardView.java:20: package com.android.phone does not exist

import com.android.phone.CallNotifier;

```
                    ^
```

But CallNotifier.java is included in the "com.android.phone" package, so if someone can please tell that how to include com.android.phone package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't include com.android.phone, it's hidden.
You *might* be able to access it via reflection but in most cases, the telephony stack is setup so that it's running in a different process and you won't be able to access anything meaningfull.

Answer (score 0):

In development case, android api is consisted of collection of abstract class. And the implemented class kept on android os. So that when you use android api, during execution it actually call that implemented classes from android os. Therefore, you actually implement that class, but it unable to find that class from os.
It'll happen if you install this app as third party, try to push your app in /system/app/ path, and reboot your device. It'll be installed.
System folder always stays in readonly mode.
Search on google about push to system tutorial.
Good luck...